# vue-router, nginx and direct link

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to setup a vue-router on my nginx server. The issue I'm having is that my route doesn't work if I enter url directly to the browser `myapp.com/mypath`.

I've tried server configuration as described in the [vue router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html#nginx) as well as suggested similar configurations on stack overflow. My current nginx location configuration as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /subscribe {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/subscribe // express API app
}
```

All that does is redirects any path to my root component (path: `/`) and not `/mypath`. This does make sense and `location` seems to only redirect to the index file. How can I redirect direct link of `myapp.com/mypath` to `/mypath` route in my VueJS app?

Here is how my vue routes setup now:

```
...
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Landing },
    { path: '/mypath', component: MyPath }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes });

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo here, but this isn't related to the issue I'm having. I've added this just in case, to show that I've got other `location` option there. I've corrected it now

Comment: Have you tried removing the `$uri/` from the first location config ? I am using this (without even configuring any other location btw) and it seems to keep the `/mypath` appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found 1 possible solution with the suggestion from a co-worker.

I'm now passing URI as a query parameter in nginx. So my config is now this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?uri=$uri
}
```

Then in my router configuration in VueJS:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: Landing,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        const { uri } = to.query;
        if (uri != null && uri != '/') {
            next(false);
            router.push(uri);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}, ...
```

This seems to do the trick, although looks a bit dodgy.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled for several hours solving the same problem. 
After all this config works for me:

```
events {
...
  http {
  ...
    server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;

          location / {
              root   /path/to/your/project/html;
              index  index.html index.htm;
              include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          }
    }
  }
}
```

I have almost the same router setup as you.

Comment: this one works perfectly, especially on this line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` which is the most important

Comment: I don't get it. The  `try_files` is exactly the same as in the original question. What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a custom publicpath (mypath) in the vue.conf and the nginx?

If so, you need to change the configuration to match to that path.

```
location /mypath {
    try_files $uri $uri/mypath /mypath/index.html
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Got to: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
2. Open the config for your domain
3. add the following code under 'root'

   ```
   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
   ```
4. save the file
5. restart your nginx server with command: `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`
6. Refresh browser

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all. It looks like a copy paste of how to configure nginx "getting started"...

Comment: this is a good answer because of the addition of index.html in the location line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `try_files` didn't work, probably because another nginx is over my app nginx, using `proxy_pass`. I had to use 404 error rewriting:

```
server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT} ssl;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};
    ssl_certificate ${NGINX_SSL_CERTIFICATE};
    ssl_certificate_key ${NGINX_SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY};
    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
    location / {
        root ${NGINX_ROOT_LOCATION};
        index  index.html;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which nginx was this in? Assuming you were still using `proxy_pass` I assume this is your app nginx config?

Comment: @Sandwich this is docker container with docker image nginx:stable-alpine

Answer (score 0):

well I had same problem so I tried to redirect every 404 errors to root url and it perfectly works.

1. Got to: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
2. Open default config file
3. add this line before location for 404 redirect:

   error_page 404 /;

save the file and don't forget to restart nginx

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is make sure you use the next line, as suggested in vue-router documentation.
But, in addition, if you have multiple files to set your nginx server,for instance a file for setting the SSL of your server,please make sure to include it also in those files.

```js
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```