# Vue.js SPA with vuex-oidc has redirect loops on release version

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vue-router, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have a single page application built in Vue.js 2.5 which also has OAuth2.0 support using IdentityServer4 + vuex-oidc and runs on an nginx server. Everything with my setup **works fine when** running the app on webpack **dev server**, but the release version has a redirect loop problem which I highly suspect might be due to nginx misconfiguration.

**Problem:** The redirect loop behavior is always the same

1. User requests navigation to /app
2. oidc plugin redirects to /connect/authorize?...
3. redirect to /app/oidc-login (authorization request's redirect uri)
4. redirect to /app (back to step 2)

For the dev server I am using a reverse proxy configured as

```
location /app {
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:55100;
    proxy_temp_path C:/myapp/nginxRP;
}
```

But since I'm using history mode in router, the release version is configured as per https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
location /app {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Where the release version of the app (index.html and static files) are located at **..\nginx\html\app**

Here's my vue-router configuration

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: "history",
    base: "/app/",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/oidc-login",
            name: "oidcCallback",
            component: OidcCallback,
            meta: {
                isOidcCallback: true,
                isPublic: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/oidc-silent-login",
            name: "oidcSilentCallback",
            component: OidcSilentCallback,
            meta: {
                isOidcCallback: false,
                isPublic: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/",
            name: HOME_PAGE_TITLE,
            component: Main
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            name: "Page Not Found",
            component: NotFound
        }
    ]
});
```

And the OidcCallback components is

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { OIDC_MODULE_NAMESPACE } from "../../store/store";

export default {
    name: "OidcCallback",
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(OIDC_MODULE_NAMESPACE, [
            "oidcSignInCallback"
        ])
    },
    mounted () {
        this.oidcSignInCallback()
            .then((redirectPath) => {
                this.$router.push(redirectPath);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
                this.$router.push("/signin-oidc-error"); // TODO
            });
    }
};
</script>
```

I've configured vuex-oidc pretty much exactly as instructed in https://github.com/perarnborg/vuex-oidc/wiki#how-to-implement-vuex-oidc except that I dynamically add the oidcStore module to vuex.

Since everything just works in the dev server and I already think this is an nginx issue, I'm not sure providing what other parts of my code/setup would be helpful but please let me know in case I'm missing something and I'll share more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected earlier, the problem was in fact a misconfiguration on the nginx part. basically the webserver was stripping the `id_token` parameter returned from IdentityServer (and any other query parameters) which resulted in the redirect loop. There are two solution to this. the easy solution is to add a rewrite rule to nginx configuration and basically replace it with something like

```
location ^~ /app/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /app/index.html;
    }
}
```

So that it correctly passes every url query to the Vue app which is then handled by Vue-Router and the vuex-oidc middleware (no changes required in setting up vue-router, only the above nginx configuration is enough). 
Another solution is to use a ["Front Controller Pattern"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#front-controller-pattern-web-apps) design and pass the complete uri with its arguments to the SPA. This still requires configuring nginx a bit differently like

```
location /app {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?route=$uri&$args;
}
```

No more rewrites, but additionally imposes special treatment in Vue-Router to perform navigation from there using a navigation guard and this `route` query similar to what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072584/vue-router-nginx-and-direct-link/49073406#49073406).