# Frontend/backend route configuration

Tags: vue.js, go, vue-router

```
$ tree .
.
├── main.go
└── static
    └── output_of_npm_run_build
```

I used vue.js with vue router for the frontend and golang for backend. What I tried to accomplish:

- use golang (either standard library or gorilla/mux) to take care of `example.com/api/...`
- vue router to take care of all vue components (`example.com`, `example.com/about`, `example.com/login`, etc.)
- RESTful APIs `example.com/post/{post_id}` for both frontend and backend

If I go to `example.com` and click the button `about`, vue router would display the `about` component and change the url to `example.com/about` without talking to the backend, which is expected. But if I enter `example.com/about` directly to the address bar and press enter, the request goes straight to the backend. Since the file `about` does not exist, it returns 404.

Is there a way to return `static/index.html` and somehow tells vue router to render `xxx` component even if `example.com/xxx` is sent directly by the browser to the server (with exception of `example.com/api`)?

Who should be responsible for routing `example.com/post/{post_id}`?

Comment: found the answer here: https://github.com/gorilla/mux#serving-single-page-applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the hosting configuration. This issue used to be happened whenever I used Front-end JS frameworks such as React, Vue and so on.

So if you type `example.com/about` manually on address bar, the page would show '404 Not Found`.

I recommend this answer to solve your issue.

[Vue router is not working with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072584/vue-router-nginx-and-direct-link)