# Direct link in Vue3 SPA

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

I have a Vue3 SPA using History and Routes.  I have just noticed that I can not goto my pages using their direct links pasted into the URL bar e.g. https://example.com/test.  Instead, I have to navigate every time first to https://example.com then click the Test button.

Here is my router.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import LandingView from './views/LandingView.vue'
import TestView from './views/TestView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/test', 
            component: TestView,
            props: true
        },
        {
            path: '/', 
            component: LandingView,
            props: true
        },
        
    ]
})
```

export default router;

From what I understand and from my SO searching, I can add the below to the above code, and have a catch all situation.

```
"navigationFallback": {
  "rewrite": "/index.html",
  "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
}
```

My issue is that is a pretty poor user experience. As such I am asking for alternatives.

Does anyone know a different way to do this so I can still use direct linking?

If there is no different way to do this, what is the standard process to change a SPA into a multiple page application?

Comment: how u serving the SPA? is there an nginx between?

Comment: Was already answered if you are using nginx:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523186/nginx-and-vuejs-3-configuration-with-baseurl-and-public-path)

Comment: In Development I have NPM sitting between..  In Prod, its "npm run build" and those file pushed to a shared hosting service with Litespeed

Comment: @Matt Then the question should be about Litespeed, if you're able to configure it that way. Web server should be configured for SPA. It's irrelevant to Vue. If you're unable to do this with your current hosting, you'll have to change it, otherwise you'll have to change the way you develop your app. "what is the standard process to change a SPA into a multiple page application?" - there's no standard process. You can switch to SSR framework (Nuxt) and use static site generation