# How to configure nginx in docker-compose in order to work with vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I have a Vue application and nginx running as a services in docker compose

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - client
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./apps/client/Dockerfile
      context: ../../
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://client:8080;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So, I am not serving static files via nginx how I would do it in bare metal, I run my vue build using http-server and then proxying nginx to look at it. Not sure if this is a viable solution, but seems to be working.

Except for one thing, but I am sure this is on nginx configuration side.

When I try to open any page other than '/', I will get 404 error, despite the app is working fine and I can reach desired url if only I start from the '/'.

Comment: It's a common error with SPAs and web servers.  Since the routing should be handled client-side nginx should redirect all requests to the same file, index.html.  I'm not an nginx expert so I'm not sure what the config would be to redirect all requests instead to your http-server, but that is the general strategy you'd need to employ. If you can switch from http-server to serving static production files, I would do that, then review [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072584).  Otherwise, hopefully someone else can provide a more thorough answer for your scenario.

Comment: I found a solution just to use common volume and serve static from that. Should be working, but got another problem :D  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782891/nginx-in-docker-compose-overwriting-my-static-files-in-the-volume