# nginx in docker-compose overwriting my static files in the volume

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

docker-compose:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - admin-dist:/apps/static/admin:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - admin
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  admin:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./apps/Blogue/admin/Dockerfile
      context: ../../
    volumes:
      - admin-dist:/app/dist

volumes:
  admin-dist:
    external: true
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      root /apps/static/admin;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Nothing special, but I got a problem. Nginx service depends on admin service, so the admin builds first. Then nginx service starts and overwrites the content of the volume with default `50x.html` and `index.html`, which are just placeholders. How to prevent nginx from doing this? Change the build order? I got a bunch of other dependencies there and I think this can be problematic and also not great solution, because it feels unstable. Any ideas?